# Meteor Collection Does not be created

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I have problem with meteor collection.

- Problem

  1. Collection Doesn't be created. 
     even though I insert code below

  > *import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';*
  >   *export const Tasks = new Mongo.collection('spartan');*

  2. Collection insert method is not executed.
  3. Return of collection is empty
- Current status

  1. I create collection like above, but It doesn't appear in windows cmd(below)

[image]

2. Collection insert method is not executed.

[image]

3. Return of (collection name).find({}) is empty(Object object)

What't wrong, Is anything to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any file inside the imports/ directory will not be loaded automatically by Meteor. You have to explicitly import the file then.

Check the article about the file structure in the meteor guide: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Answer (score 1):

I find out that "It is caused by file structure."

Actually I put my code "export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks')" into 'imports/api/tasks.js', but after I putting my code onto the 'lib'. It works!!!

And I refer to this answer from here "https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-collection-insert-fail-insert-failed-method-not-found/12762/9"

Thanks.

Comment: Most of all, I am not defining collection in server. 
- Defining collection in server is implemented by putting import code("import ../imports/api/tasks.js") into "server/main.js"